# Defining a function using a parameter not given as its argument [Racket]

Tags: racket

I want to define functions in Racket which uses a parameter not given as its argument but will be defined in the scope. Is this possible?

For instance,

```
(define (fun1 x) (get-value x data))

(define (another-function args . data) 
  ... (map (eval '((fun1 . x) (fun2 . y)))) ...
)
```

`fun1` needs to refer a data structure but it will be given as an argument in the functions from which `fun1` will be called

I am not experienced in Racket, and couldn't find a solution for my problem in the web. Sorry for any inconvenience, and thank you for the responses.

Edit:

I should give a more precise explanation.

The point is, I don't use a data structure like `struct`. Instead, I give a list containing data, apply some changes to it, and return the updated data.

The problematic part is, since my data is given as an argument, when I define a function somewhere else *I can't use this data* and thus I got an error for `unbound identifier`

A code snippet:

```
(define (var x) (get-value x data)) ;Should return value of x from data
;Error due to previous part: "unbound identifier in module in: data"
(define (myapply func expr data) (eval (cons(func (map (eval expr))))))

> (myapply '+ '((var x) (var y)) '((x 3) (y 4)))
7
```

Comment: I'm not sure if your question is specified good enough. Could you give me an example of `get-value` and an actual use and expected result from `another-function`?

Comment: So if you do `(myapply '+ '(3 (var x) (var x)) '((x 10)))` the result is 23? (Im trying to figure out why you use an alist with `var` as keys. I'm betting you have perhaps constants in adition to variables or else you could have used `(myapply '+ '(x y) '((x 3) (y 4))`. Also in an actual interpreter the usual thing is to evaluate all the arguments so you have a list of resolved values to apply. Even the function is resolved so it's perhaps not a symbol at all. Thus `(myapply + (map (lambda (x) (myeval x env)) args) env)` for primitives.

Comment: @Sylwester yes it should give 23. I don't just write `'(x y)` because `(var x)` isn't the only function used like this. There might be other functions like `(value x) ;returns x` and also we might call `(myapply '+ '((var x) (my apply '* '((value 5) (var y)))) '((x 2) (y 3)))` So I use `eval` to be able to evaluate all functions value,var,myapply, and others. If I truncate `'((var x) (var y))` to `'(x y)` I can't map eval to all elements.

Comment: Why not? what does a sole symbol evaluate to in your evaluator?

Answer (score 1):

We have standard lexical closures. Eg. we can make a curry procedure:

```scm
(define (curry proc arg)
  (lambda args
    (apply proc arg args)))

(define add-10 (curry + 10))
(add-10 5) ; ==> 15
```

If you want a value to be changed dynamically. eg. that you can change behavior of one procedure by setting a variable while you call it it's caled dynamic variables. Dynamic variables are available in `#!racket` using [parameters](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/parameters.html). Here is an example:

```scm
#!racket

(define p (make-parameter 10))

(define (list-3-p)
  (let ((p-val (p)))
    (list p-val p-val p-val)))

(define (override-p-parameter new-val thunk)
  (parameterize ([p new-val]) ; we override p momentarily to a new value
    (thunk)))                 ; but it restores to it's initial value after

(list-3-p)                          ; (10 10 10)
(override-p-parameter 20 list-3-p)  ; (20 20 20) 
(list-3-p)                          ; (10 10 10)
```

If `p` were a normal lexical variable this would not work:

```scm
#!racket

(define p 10)

(define (list-3-p)
  (let ((p-val p))
    (list p-val p-val p-val)))

(define (override-p-parameter new-val thunk)
  (let ([p new-val]) ; we override p momentarily to a new value
    (thunk)))        ; but it won't change `p` in thunk because of lexical scoping.

(list-3-p)                          ; (10 10 10)
(override-p-parameter 20 list-3-p)  ; (10 10 10) 
(list-3-p)                          ; (10 10 10)
```

Comment: First suggestion is very close to what I want. But in this example, it is explicitly stated that `curry` will be used in `add-10` and arguments of `add-10` aren't stated in its own definition. Can we make this more general, for instance, there are 5 functions like `add-10` to use 3 functions like `curry` but we can't standardize their arguments like this?